# Transfer or Extract Computed Data from One Python File to Another

Tags: python, casadi

AA computes a function using a software called CasADi.
I have installed CasADi, and AA can run on my desktop.

BB has to run in a container and imports data from AA.Because of this, BB cannot run because it doesn't recognize CasADi

How can I change the import statement in file BB to extract data from AA, which is in a different location. Both AA and BB are python files

I have tried the following import statements. Both did not work.

```
from AA import c_A
```

```
from home.user.Desktop.AA import c_A
```

Comment: Do the host and the container share any disk directories?  If not, then you need to treat them as two separate computers.  You'll have to use something like a socket to send the data.

Comment: no they don't. How would I use a socket to send the data?

Comment: What are you sending?  Is it just a numeric array, or some more complicated data structure?

Comment: Just a numpy array

Comment: Any luck with the answers you received?

Comment: No, so I extracted the data into a csv file and moved that csv file to the container. That works better

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a way to copy files into the container, it's not too hard.  In your AA script, you can do:

```
import numpy as np
...
# Assume the numpy array is in variable "array".
np.save( "transfer.npy", array )
```

Now, you would have to take a manual to copy the file into the container.  Once in the container, in your BB script, you can do:

```
import numpy as np
...
array = numpy.load( "transfer.npy" )
```

and that will work.

If you don't have a way to copy files, then you would have to use a TCP client/server thing.  That takes more coordination, because one side has to be a server, which runs FIRST and sits and waits for the other side to check in.  After they're connected, you can use `np.save` to save the file to a `io.BytesIO` object, which acts just like a file, then send the contents over the socket.  There are many examples on the web of simple TCP socket exchanges in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @TimRoberts answer, but showing how to bind mount and share a directory on your desktop with your docker instance...

In AA, save the array on your Desktop using `np.save("/home/YOURUSER/Desktop/transfer.npy", data)`.

Then start BB in docker, but using a *"bind mount"* of your Desktop to a folder called `/data` in docker:

```
docker run -v "$HOME/Desktop:/data" ...
```

Then in BB, load the file with:

```
import numpy as np
na = np.load("/data/transfer.npy")
```

---

If you wanted a bit more of a dynamic/interactive interchange between the two processes without involving disk files, you could spin up another docker container with the standard Redis image in it, then you could easily exchange commands/data/Numpy arrays via Redis - see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55313342/2836621).